# It is not ouputting values in array when echoed

Tags: php

I think there is a problem when I echo $whereArray and orderByArray. If I type in a word such as "Question" and then submit it, I expect it to display in the echos "%".Question."%"; for both arrays. But instead in both echos it just displays "Array" for both echos. Does this mean that both arrays are not working when it comes to storing in the values?

```
 $searchquestion = $_GET['questioncontent'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $searchquestion);

$whereArray = array();
$orderByArray = array();


    //loop through each term
    foreach ($terms as $each) {
        $i++;
        $whereArray[] = "%".$each."%";
        $orderByArray[] = "%".$each."%"; 


    }

        echo $whereArray;
        echo $orderByArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var_dump` or `print_r` instead of `echo` (they are functions, not constructs like `echo` is).

Comment: It has nothing to do with being a function or a construct.  `echo` just doesn't deep toString arrays like the other functions do.

Comment: @mellamokb what I meant was that functions need parentheses.

Comment: You should be able to do `var_dump $a;` as well as `echo($a);` depending on your configuration. I think mellamokb meant that your reasoning is wrong, even if the answer is right.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Gotcha, I thought that was your explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

`echo()` only works for strings. PHP converts your array to `"Array"` as a fallback.

When you're debugging, you should use `var_dump()`. It will tell you the type of the object and its content.

Answer (score 1):

An array needs to be printed out using a special function such as print_r. If you want to print out a value in your array try:

```
echo $whereArray[0];
```

To get the first element. Be careful because if the array is empty you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

you can also loop through them

```
foreach($arrayname as $value)
     echo $value;
```

or

```
  echo implode("",$arrayname);
```